# Lock writes to HashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a HashMap which is being updated asynchronously. I need to perform operations involving the map which require the map does not change state during the task, for example sorting values based on the contents of the map.

Is there a way of locking a map so that only reads can happen which is blocking to all write threads, so after the map is unlocked all modifications can happen? The lock needs to be able to allow multiple threads to write at the same time as I am using a ConcurrentHashMap and I would like to take advantage of the benefits of a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Why don't you try to use ConcurrentHashMap ?

Comment: @TugrulAsik: ConcurrentHashMap has no option to lock the whole thing, and using a separate lock defeats the benefit of using a ConcurrentHashMap. You might as well wrap a lock around a regular HashMap.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: You *might* get a performance advantage from wrapping a ReadWriteLock around a ConcurrentHashMap and having writers use the read lock, long-running read operations use the write lock, and readers who can tolerate the map changing under them use neither, if only one long-running read operation happens at a time. I'm wary about the double synchronization overhead, though. Maybe time it and see how it compares to a HashMap protected with a regular lock.

Comment: @user2248702 if there is an answer that has solved your problem, you should accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConcurrentHashMap does not offer thread safety between methods calls, only within a single call.  Thus if you want to keep the map unchanged while performing an operation, you will need to wrap the calls to the map with your own lock.

For example, using a ReadWriteLock:

```
ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

When you are updating the map

```
readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();

// do the updates

readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
```

and when you want to read from the map

```
readWriteLock.readLock().lock();

// perform the read and its operations that rely on the map not changing

readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
```

Comment: As far as I know a ReadWriteLock only allows 1 writer thread at a time, is this correct and if so what could I use to be able to write with multiple threads?

Comment: @user2248702 - You could use a `ConcurrentHashMap` to accomplish that with added disadvantage - *All writes will not be seen in subsequent reads*.

Comment: @user2248702 your understanding is correct, ReadWriteLock is single writer, multiple readers.  Multiple writers would be difficult to achieve.  You could follow TheLostMind's suggestion, or stripe the map.  That is have an outer map, that wraps n other maps where each delegate map has its own read/write lock.  You can then select the delegate map via the hashcode of the key.  But first, I would suggest keeping it simple and demonstrate that a single writer solution bottlenecks before adding more complexity.

Comment: @ChrisK Is there any kind of MultiWriteLock where I could call something like lock.lock() which would block all calls to lock.write() for example and lock.unlock() would unlock the lock and allow threads waiting to write to continue?

Comment: @user2248702 Looking for examples of Striping, I came across a Guava implementation  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.java;  I have never used this version but you may get some mileage from it.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the ReentrantReadWriteLock backwards? There's nothing anywhere that says that when you have locked the writeLock you must be writing. I know it's ugly, but you could use the readLock() for writes and the writeLock() for reads.

Comment: @Rich lol. You are right, that is ugly.  But it would achieve what the OP is asking for.  I question the semantics of multiple writers and single reader though.. it sounds like there is a bigger design problem here.  Perhaps more detail on why this situation arises would help.

Comment: I've added my suggestion as an answer - it will be easier for debate :)

Answer (score 6):

Why not use a `ConcurrentHashMap` protected by a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` but use it backwards?

```
myLock.writeLock().lock();
try {
    return myMap.get(...);
} finally {
    myLock.writeLock().unlock();
}
```

and

```
myLock.readLock().lock();
try {
    myMap.put(..., ...);
} finally {
    myLock.readLock().unlock();
}
```

This is quite ugly and it would need covering in comments in order to warn an uninitiated subsequent developer that you were actually writing when holding the `readLock` and reading when holding the `writeLock` but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

For clarity you could even write your own `InversedReentrantReadWriteLock` which wraps the real `ReentrantReadWriteLock` to inverse the calls and make the code more readable.

If, as @GPI suggested, you want to either be in a read mode or a write mode but retain concurrency within that mode, you could use `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong` to implement a lock. A positive value could represent being in read mode, and a negative value write mode. Being at zero would indicate that the lock could move into either mode. This immediately becomes more complicated as you will have to implement the lock yourself whereas the concurrent-writes-with-exclusive-reads solution outlined above relies solely on existing API classes. (I'm sure I could work one out if you want but I wouldn't be able to provide an answer immediately)

Comment: I'm not sure... it's ugly but it seems to work for what I want it to.

Comment: This will cause reads to be single threaded. I think the OP has in mind (multi threaded reads) or (multi threaded writes), with "or" being a mutual exclusion.

Comment: Commenting code should always be a last resort--to be used only when you are doing something so evil that there is no other way to explain it:  Before I add comments I would try wrapping the ReadWriteLock in another class with a class name and method names that explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping your HashMap into a class where you put some kind of

```
boolean isLocked
```

Assume you want to start the reading process from a thread, you can just check for this lock

```
if(!myClass.getLockState())
{ //perform whatever you want to do }
```

If you make sure all threads work with the same `myClass` object this could be a simple solution for locking/unlocking your hashMap.

Comment: OK, so thread A calls geetLockState(), finds it to be false, and begins to do whatever.  What happens if, at that moment, thread B then locks the lock and changes the contents of the map?

Comment: @james large hmmmm you are right...stupid me :) But if you could put all the modifying "requests" in a `concurrentLinkedQueue` and a single thread actually reads that queue and performs the changings to the map? All other Threads would ve read access only.